# Remove all entries from location/address bar in Windows 8.1/Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows

I want to clear all the files/folders Ive been to that if you click the drop down arrow next, to the right, of the address/location bar in Windows 8.1/Windows Server 2012 R2, show.

How can I do this without using any third party tools?

Comment: Use Something like CCleaner to clear the MRU lists from the registry.

Comment: Without using any third party tools

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all the entries under the following registry key should accomplish what you want:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TypedPaths
```